# Shape background as image

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to set shape color as image, but failing to do so. Maybe anyone could tell me how to do this in a proper way? I use this shape as my background for buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     android:shape="rectangle">
    
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
    
        <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#ff0000" />
        
        <solid android:color= "@drawable/tableback1" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in way you presented it in question.

As per documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape `solid.color` attribute value must be a *color and not a drawable*. This color is used as a fill for the whole shape. You're passing a `drawable` which is seen here:

```
<solid android:color= "@drawable/tableback1" />
```

Instead it should be something along the lines:

```
<solid android:color="@color/background_color1" />
```

Or simply:

```
<solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
```

Comment: The problem is I have nice transparent color in "tableback" image. I could set the same color like you just said, but how to make it transparent lets say 50 precent?

Comment: specify the alpha value as the first component. for example this is 100% red: `#ffff0000`, this is 50% red: `#80ff0000`, this is 25% blue: `#4000ff00`, and so on. you can find more examples and reference here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: Great. This is what I was looking for.. I will mark your answer as accepted as it does answer my question, even through we real answer i was looking lies in comments :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Datenshi you're welcome. the answer-in-comment is very common since the question is rarely well-defined at first. I for example didn't know if your intention was to repeat a bitmap as background of the rectangle for example. glad we sorted that out. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

As you can set the starting two value for color as alpha with total 8 digits for example

```
#00ffaa44 // here is the fully transparent

#88ffaa44 // semi transparent

#ffffaa44 // fully opaque
```

you can maintain your color with alpha value as per your requirement